# Why am I unable to set organization name?

Tags: wordpress

CiviCRM 4.4

I am trying to set the organization name and address details but the form is not displaying correctly. There are no input fields, only a white screen.

I added some debug stuff to wp-config.php. I then got: `Fatal error: Smarty error: [in CRM/common/formButtons.tpl line 38]: [plugin] unknown tag - 'crmGetAttribute' (core.load_plugins.php, line 118) in /home/vietfeir/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Sm‌​arty.class.php on line 1094` Where do I go from here? I searched for this error in forums.civicrm.org but could not find any reference to this error.

[image: Organization Name screen not showing fields Wordpress Site]

Answer (score 1):

`crmGetAttribute` is not in 4.4, that only exists in later versions of CiviCRM. So either:

- You are using an extension that is not compatible with 4.4, or
- You have copied a template file from a later version of CiviCRM onto your install, or
- You have somehow managed to get your 4.4 files mixed up with code from a later version

The best solution for any of these situations would be for you to upgrade to the latest version of CiviCRM. If you follow the [upgrade procedure](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress) correctly, this will ensure you have a clean copy of the latest source code.

Comment: This was a pristine installation and the upgrade procedures were followed.

I'm going to wait until the MailChimp extension is upgraded to run with 4.6. This issue can be closed.

Comment: You can answer your own question (saying what caused the error) and then mark your answer as the accepted one. This will help others who come along with a similar problem.